# Ionic Rest API login

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I have checked the API is working in Postman and Login Credentials are working
but it always shows that "Enter valid email and password" this toast message always pops up

```
  login() {
   console.log('form.email: ' + this.email);
  if (this.password !== '' && this.email !== '') {
  this.commonService.showLoader('');
  this.auth.userLogin(this.email, this.password).then(resp => {
    const data = JSON.parse(resp.data);
    console.log('data login: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    if (data.cust === 'Login Success') {
      localStorage.setItem('login_status', '1');
      this.commonService.hideLoader();
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
      this.commonService.presentToast('Login Success');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      } else if (data.error_warning !== '') {
      this.commonService.hideLoader();
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
      this.commonService.hideLoader();
      this.commonService.presentToast('Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or 
     Password.');
    } else{
      this.commonService.presentToast('Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or 
     Password.');
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
    }
    }).catch(error => {
    this.email = '';
    this.password = '';
    this.commonService.presentToast('Enter valid email and password');
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    this.commonService.hideLoader();
    console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
   } else {
   this.email = '';
   this.password = '';
   this.commonService.presentToast('please fill email and password');
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Toast comes up after an error, which triggers the catch in your promise. Could there be an error in the first part of your if statement or before?

```
if (data.cust === 'Login Success') {
   localStorage.setItem('login_status', '1');
   this.commonService.hideLoader();
   this.email = '';
   this.password = '';
   this.commonService.presentToast('Login Success');
   this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```